# Query by custom meta, current date and proper query format

Tags: wordpress

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields to add fields to an Event custom post type. 
The relevant fields are `event_date`, and `feature_event`.

Posts are sorted by event_date and a featured event is chosen with feature_event where if the checkbox "yes" is chosen that Event is displayed in the featured section, if not the next most recent event is shown.

This is set-up and working fine with this code:

```
$args=array(
 'post_type' => 'event',
 'post_status' => 'publish',
 'posts_per_page' => 1,
 'order' => 'ASC',
 'orderby' => 'meta_value',
 'meta_query' => array(
       'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'feature_event',
            'value' => 'yes',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
   )
);
```

I've also got the remaining events sorted in a different query where if the event date has passed the event no longer displays, this is set up and working fine with this code, which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17455484/query-posts-by-custom-meta-and-current-date):

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'event', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'event_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
            array(
               'key' => 'event_date',
               'meta-value' => $value,
               'value' => $today,
               'compare' => '>=',
               'type' => 'datetime'// you can change it to datetime also
           )
    )
);
```

Where I'm stuck is I'd like to have the first query to show the featured event but if the date has passed to not show that event, same as the second query above, basically combining the two queries.

I have tried adding the second array to the meta_query but even if the day has passed the event still shows if it is selected as a featured event.

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$args=array(
 'post_type' => 'event',
 'post_status' => 'publish',
 'posts_per_page' => 1,
 'order' => 'ASC',
 'orderby' => 'meta_value',
 'meta_query' => array(
       'relation' => 'OR',
          array(
            'key' => 'feature_event',
            'value' => 'yes',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'event_date',
            'meta-value' => $value,
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'datetime'
        )
  )
);
```

Could someone show me the proper method for combining these two queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it yourself.....just use "and" instead of "or" in your final code and put in your conditions there.

e.g.

```
'meta_query' => array(
   'relation' => 'AND',
      array(
        'key' => 'feature_event',
        'value' => 'yes',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'event_date',
        'meta-value' => $value,
        'value' => $today,
        'compare' => '>=',
        'type' => 'datetime'
    ),
    array(
    'key'=>'blah',
    etc
    )
```

)